# Excel - Insert a space at the top of cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

For some reason, my boss insists on making calendars in excel, and we essentially use large tables to accomplish this. Text is place in each cell and it is usually horizontally centered and vertically aligned to the top. What I have been told to do is to insert a blank space in between the text and and the top of the cell so that the text isn't right up against the cell border, but for some reason I cannot figure out how to do this. Perhaps it is not possible. If only there was a way to vertically indent, but still have horizontal text. Any thoughts?

Comment: Would aligning to bottom and increasing the row height do the trick?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but Alt-Enter inserts a line break in a cell

Answer (score 0):

Use Middle align and center in the Alignment Group (Home Tab)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. type the text in the cell
2. set vertical alignment to `Top`
3. click in the Formula Bar at the beginning of the text
4. touch <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This will insert a hard return at the beginning of the text and force it down from the upper boundary.